# How can I adjust the position of an image using React?

Tags: css, reactjs, image

I have an image I'm trying to add to my home page to the right of some text and am having difficulty doing so. I'm a little new to React and have tried a few things, including using CSS, but nothing seems to be working. I have a feeling it's because of the root: make styles, but could be wrong. Any ideas how to get an image placed? Here is my code:
[image]

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { AppBar, Button, IconButton, Collapse} from '@material-ui/core';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore';
import { Link as Scroll } from 'react-scroll';
import image2 from '../pages/image2.png';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'flex',
    height: '100vh',
    fontFamily: 'sans-serif',
    background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)',
  },
  colorText: {
    color: 'black',
    fontWeight: 600,
  },
  container: {
    alighnItems:'flex',
    textAlign: 'left',
    paddingTop: '200px',
    paddingLeft: '60px',

  },
  title: {
    color: 'black',
    fontSize: '4rem',
    fontWeight: 400,
    
  },
  
}));

export default function Home() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    setChecked(true);
  }, []);
  return (
       <div className={classes.root} id="header">
      <Collapse
        in={checked}
        {...(checked ? { timeout: 1000 } : {})}
        collapsedHeight={50}
      >
        <div className={classes.container}>
          <h1 className={classes.title}>
            Level the playing field <br /> 
            with<span className={classes.colorText}> Level Finance.  </span>
          </h1>
          <Scroll to="place-to-visit" smooth={true}>
            <Button variant="contained">Learn More
            </Button>
          </Scroll>
        </div>
      </Collapse>
    </div>
    
      );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an image in react, do it just like you would HTML; But set the source to the

```
<img src="<source-of-image>"/>
```

Once you place it, you have to position it within your document using css. Example:

```
import "./styles.css";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { AppBar, Button, IconButton, Collapse } from "@material-ui/core";
import ExpandMoreIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore";
import { Link as Scroll } from "react-scroll";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "flex",
    height: "100vh",
    fontFamily: "sans-serif",
    background: "linear-gradient(45deg, #FE6B8B 30%, #FF8E53 90%)"
  },
  colorText: {
    color: "black",
    fontWeight: 600
  },
  container: {
    alighnItems: "flex",
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "row",
    textAlign: "left",
    paddingTop: "200px",
    paddingLeft: "60px"
  },
  img: {
    width: "200px",
    height: "200px"
  },
  title: {
    color: "black",
    fontSize: "4rem",
    fontWeight: 400
  }
}));

export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    setChecked(true);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className={classes.root} id="header">
      <Collapse
        in={checked}
        {...(checked ? { timeout: 1000 } : {})}
        collapsedHeight={50}
      >
        <div className={classes.container}>
          <div>
            <h1 className={classes.title}>
              Level the playing field <br />
              with<span className={classes.colorText}> Level Finance. </span>
            </h1>
            <Scroll to="place-to-visit" smooth={true}>
              <Button variant="contained">Learn More</Button>
            </Scroll>
          </div>
          <img
            className={classes.img}
            alt="Did it"
            src="https://media3.giphy.com/media/cklPOHnHepdwBLRnQp/giphy.gif"
          />
        </div>
      </Collapse>
    </div>
  );
}
```